# How can I find out if a kernel upgrade has caused my hardware to stop working?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, bluetooth, intel-graphics

## Short question:

How can I find out if a kernel upgrade has caused my hardware to stop working?

## Longer version:

If I understand correctly:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 used kernel version 4.4
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 uses kernel version 4.8

I have a hunch that the bluetooth and graphics on my Gigabyte Brix no longer work properly as a result of upgrading from kernel version 4.4 to 4.8. (To be clear, they worked fine with fresh install Ubuntu 16.04.1, they do not work properly with fresh install Ubuntu 16.04.2 or fully-upgraded 16.04.2.)

How can I find out if kernel version 4.4 supported a particular piece of hardware and 4.8 does not?

(In case it is relevant, the precise problems are: **bluetooth** won't discover some things and will connect but won't otherwise work with other things; **graphics** see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892245/pointer-wont-display-at-the-left-edge-of-screen).)

Here are some details about the hardware:

```
rowand@rowand-desktop:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for rowand: 
rowand-desktop            
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: GB-BACE-3160 (Default string)
    vendor: GIGABYTE
    version: 1.x
    serial: Default string
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Default string sku=Default string uuid=<removed>
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: MZBSWMP-00
       vendor: GIGABYTE
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.x
       serial: Default string
       slot: Default string
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J3160  @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 34
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU J3160 @ 1.60GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 991MHz
          capacity: 2400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 80MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 35
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:313 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:309 memory:81500000-8150ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.8.0-42-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Please say if more information is required.

Comment: You can roll back to the old kernel, and see if stuff starts working.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/700214/how-do-i-install-an-old-kernel

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. Thanks for your help. I tried that but it didn’t make any difference. I suppose that is useful information. (In other news, the bluetooth problem is gone, not sure why or how, and there is progress of a kind on the graphics issue, see the update on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892245/pointer-wont-display-at-the-left-edge-of-screen).)